# Extract numbers after each occurrence of a substring

Tags: php, regex, extract, preg-match-all

My input:

```
$string = " text1 .id.123 .id.4576 text4 .id.56778 text 5 .id.76728";
```

How can I get output with php?

Extract number after `.id.`

Desired result:

```
123,4576,56778,76728
```

Comment: Use regex to extract numbers following id.

Comment: Try https://www.php.net/preg_match_all and update your post if you run into problems.

Comment: @tis you are receiving downvotes because you have shown no coding effort or research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match a literal dot, then `id`, then a literal dot, then reset the fullstring match with `\K`, then match one or more digits.

Implode the matches with commas.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EDW2V))

```
$string = " text1 .id.123 .id.4576 text4 .id.56778 text 5 .id.76728";
preg_match_all('~\.id\.\K\d+~', $string, $m);

echo implode(',', $m[0]);
// 123,4576,56778,76728
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all` and a pattern such as

```
if (preg_match_all('#\.id\.(\d+)\b#', $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // $number = (int) $match[1];
        var_dump($match);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed it above; the boundary at the start was a problem